# Which devices is my app having problems

Tags: android, testing, android-testing

So my problem is simple: 
I developed a really cool app and it works great on my device, however I have knowledge that it is not working on other devices.

Is there an analytic, dashboard, API or something that can help me find out which problems are specific devices having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Acra](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) highly recomended.

Answer (score 1):

The developer console lists the device(s) that the crash happened on as well as the stack trace

link (might work): https://play.google.com/apps/publish/

or just goto http://developer.android.com and the link is in the top right corner of the overflow menu on the website

Edit:

If the user chooses to report the error (thanks cjk)